# Project written in swift language can be run in iOS 6 device?

Tags: ios, swift

When run one project written in swift language from Xcode 6.1 in iOS 6 device, I got following error :

Swift is unavailable on iOS earlier than 7.0; please set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 7.0 or later (currently it is '6.0').

Is there any way to project written in swift in iOS 6 device?

Comment: Any reason for down voting the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest answer of your query is NO.